# laravel create model from custom stub when using php artisan

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-artisan, stub

When I use `php artisan make:model CustomNamespace\TestModel`, I get a model based on default stub as this :

```
namespace App\Models\CustomNamespace;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class TestModel extends Model
{
    //
}
```

But what I want to create is a dynamic Model based on my own stub to get something like this:

```
namespace App\Models\CustomNamespace;

use App\Models\MyParent;
/**
 * Put a dynamic doc here
 */
class MyModel extends MyParent
{
    /*put custom methods here*/
}
```

I've checked Laravel docs and other tutos but nothing on this, could you help guys ?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 11):

Create a new command, extend the `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ModelMakeCommand` class and override the `getStub()` method:

```
protected function getStub()
{
    if ($this->option('pivot')) {
        return __DIR__.'/stubs/pivot.model.stub';
    }

    return storage_path('/stubs/my-own-model.stub');
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since Laravel 7, you can apply [stub customization](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#stub-customization) by running:

```sh
php artisan stub:publish
```

This command will publish all the stub files that are used for the `artisan make` commands in the `stubs` directory of the application root, and give you the ability to change them according to your project's needs.

One of them is `stubs/model.stub`:

```php
<?php

namespace {{ namespace }};

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class {{ class }} extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Change it to:

```php
<?php

namespace {{ namespace }};

use App\Models\MyParent;

/**
 * Put your documentation here
 */
class {{ class }} extends MyParent
{
    /* Put your custom methods here */
}
```

You can read a bit more about stub customization in [this blog post](https://arievisser.com/blog/how-to-use-stub-customization-in-laravel/).