# Enforce Global Scope Across all models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-spark

we are developing an application based on Laravel Spark. as part of this we want to tie resources to a specfic team.

I know that we can add a global scope such as:

```
<?php


namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class TeamScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('team_id', '=',Auth()->user()->currentTeam->id );
    }
}
```

but according to the docs we have to add that to each model that we want to restrict like so:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(new TeamScope);
}
```

my issue with this is that it will be possible to create future models and forget to apply this code. Which could give us a security hole?

is there any way to enforce the scope across the board?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there's a way to globally add the Scope.

In my particular application, we have had to add more responsiblities to our Models. So we created a `BaseModel` class that extends Laravel's `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

All new Models then extends the `BaseModel` instead of Laravel's one.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BaseModel extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(new TeamScope);
    }

}
```

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Attribute extends BaseModel
{

}
```

You could also have a trait that you can just use to add this scope to your Model. For example:

```
trait HasTeamScope
{
    protected static function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();
            static::addGlobalScope(new TeamScope);
        }
    }
}
```

... and then you can easily re-use that in your Model.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Attribute extends BaseModel
{
    use HasTeamScope;
}
```

Now, based on your question, you might also forget to extend the BaseModel in the first instance or add the Trait in the second one whenever you create a new model.

To solve this, you could easily [create a new command to produce models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48384903/laravel-create-model-from-custom-stub-when-using-php-artisan) that will use your own stub (which extends the BaseModel or adds the trait whenever you create a new model)

Comment: yeah I had considered those two options. I guess i was hoping for the magic bullet that would make it something that could not be forgotted. We have added a command for now to generate the models. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own base model with the desired global scope that future models would extend.

Answer (score 0):

You should create trait with boot function. Trait named BelongsToTeam.

And in all models add only: use BelongsToTeam;

Comment: This still has the same issue, if someone forgets to add the trait then that model can be access across teams